# ABP Feature Management - How to add a new scope?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am developing an event management application with ASP.NET Boilerplate and Module Zero.

The features management included with ASP.NET Boilerplate allows to scope features to an Edition or to a Tenant.

I would like to know if it's possible to extend features to be scoped to events, so I can assign specific features of our application individually to each event our tenants create.

Is this possible? What is the best way to implement this with ABP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if it's possible to extend features to be scoped to events... Is this possible?

Sure. You can:

- subclass `Feature`
- subclass `FeatureSetting`
- **create a new `FeatureScopes` enum to include `Events`**
- implement and replace `IFeatureChecker`
- implement and replace `IFeatureManager`
- override methods in `FeatureValueStore`

That looks like a lot of work. But it is done like that for maintainability and separation of concerns.

> What is the best way to implement this with ABP?

You're better off using `Feature` as-is, enabled for the tenant, and then replace [`FeatureChecker`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/679199091d87acc43b83d02dde60f533e1c6d094/src/Abp/Application/Features/FeatureChecker.cs):

```cs
public async Task<string> GetValueAsync(int tenantId, string name)
{
    var feature = _featureManager.Get(name);

    var value = await FeatureValueStore.GetValueOrNullAsync(tenantId, feature);
    if (value == null)
    {
        return feature.DefaultValue;
    }

    // Check if Feature is enabled for Event
    // ...

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the simplest solution is to create an Entity called `EventFeature` where I can store the mappings between Events and Features and then replace `FeatureChecker` to lookup those features inside events. Im going to evaluate how to inject the event session into the FeatureChecker the same way `AbpSession` is injected.

Comment: Hello Aaron, I have implemented my own FeatureChecker but I am having trouble making Abp use it instead of the default FeatureChecker. I have added ITransientDependency to my FeatureChecker but it's still picking the Abp default one. Any idea on how to do that registration correctly?

Comment: You should call `Configuration.ReplaceService<IEmailSender, NullEmailSender>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);` in the `PreInitialize` method of your module.